# Ramsey theory & Big data problem

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ramsey-theory

How is Ramsey theory used in Big data analysis? 
Can you suggest me some books or research papers on this subject.

Comment: possibly related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532685/does-big-data-have-a-ramsey-theory-problem

Answer (score 1):

[Using Ramsey theory to measure unavoidable spurious correlations in Big Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09471) by 
Micheal Pawliuk and Michael Alexander Waddell

Abstract:

Given a dataset we quantify how many patterns must always exist in the dataset. Formally this is done through the lens of Ramsey theory of graphs, and a quantitative bound known as Goodman's theorem. Combining statistical tools with Ramsey theory of graphs gives a nuanced understanding of how far away a dataset is from random, and what qualifies as a meaningful pattern. 
This method is applied to a dataset of repeated voters in the 1984 US congress, to quantify how homogeneous a subset of congressional voters is. We also measure how transitive a subset of voters is. Statistical Ramsey theory is also used with global economic trading data to provide evidence that global markets are quite transitive.

See also Cristian Calude, Giuseppe Longo. [The Deluge of Spurious Correlations in Big Data.](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01380626/document) Lois des dieux, des hommes et de la nature, Oct 2015, Nantes, France. pp.1 - 18, 10.1007/s10699-016-9489-4 . hal- 01380626